# ComboBox ItemTemplate is not working with KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, wpf

My `ComboBox` items need to be something like:

"Some Text 10.00 Other Text 1.00"

I tried the code bellow, but it's not working. It throws an exception.

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   WindowsBase.dll

`MyKeyValuePairArray` is `List<KeyValuePair<decimal, decimal>>`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static static:MyApp.MyKeyValuePairArray}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Some Text" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                <Run Text="Other Text" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

That works, but I need the above template:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static static:MyApp.MyKeyValuePairArray}}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
          SelectedValuePath="Key"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS writes in the Output window:

"TwoWay or OneWayToSource Binding cannot work with readonly properties Key and Value"

change binding Mode explicitly:

```
<Run Text="Some Text" />
<Run Text="{Binding Path=Key, Mode=OneWay}" />
<Run Text="Other Text" />
<Run Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
```